# Add value of a method to serde serialization output

Tags: rust

Is there a way to add the value of a  method to the serialization output of `serde` when the struct derives `Serialize`? I'm looking for something like a "virtual field".

I know I can define my own `Serializer` / `Visitor` or use `serde_json::builder` to get a `Value`, I just wanted to check first if there was any way to do this using `serde_macro` magic.

To be clear I want something like this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: String,
    #[serde(call="Foo::baz")]
    baz: i32 // but this is not a real field
}

impl Foo {
    fn baz(&self) -> i32 { self.bar.len() as i32 }
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster, thanks for the suggestion! I just added a simple example of using a wrapper--is this what you mean? This is definitely easier/simpler than defining a builder or serializer, but isn't really ideal...

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I am using now. It's still verbose, and I don't know if it is the best way to handle this, but I thought I would add it here for the record:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: String
}

impl Foo {
    fn baz(&self) -> i32 { self.bar.len() as i32 }
}

impl ::serde::Serialize for Foo {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer {

        #[derive(Serialize)]
        struct Extended<'a> {
            bar: &'a String,
            baz: i32
        }

        let ext = Extended {
            bar: &self.bar,
            baz: self.baz()
        };

        Ok(ext.serialize(serializer)?)
    }
}
```